# Discover the custom schema formats a Windows Store App shares on?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to discover/inspect any custom data formats a Windows Store Application exposes via the Share charm?  Not referring to simple Text/Html/Link/File/(other standard) formats that can be received/shared, but actual custom data schema formats.

I know that apps need to declare what formats and schemas are supported for receiving data [via the manifesto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465255.aspx).

For example, the following code snippet from the MSDN docs on [sharing data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771179.aspx):

```
function shareCustomData() {
    var dataTransferManager = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.addEventListener("datarequested", function (e) {
        var request = e.request;
        request.data.setData("http://schema.org/Book", book);
    });
}
```

The above would mean that a Windows Store App that is wanting to receive the shared data would need to declare that it specifically supports the `http://schema.org/Book` schema. However, if an app developer doesn't publicly document what schemas their app shares on, or shares on a non-standard schema not specifically listed on schema.org, is there any way to inspect/discover/catch-all schemas that are broadcast via the Share charm?

Obviously I'm looking for a way to hook into and discover this data without needing to list out any/all published schema.org schemas that you're remotely interested in and hope that the app shares on a schema.org standard schema.